# Using SDL_BlitScaled to created scaled copies of surfaces

Tags: c, graphics, sdl, sdl-2

So I'm working on some SDL2 Wrapper stuff, and I'm trying to use SDL_BlitScaled to copy the data in a src surface into a destination surface which I've already created, like so

```
SDL_Surface *loaded = IMG_Load("test.png");
SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(loaded, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
SDL_Surface *out = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 100, 100, loaded->format->BitsPerPixel, 
                                        loaded->format->Rmask, loaded->format->Gmask, loaded->format->Bmask, loaded->format->Amask);
SDL_BlitScaled(loaded, NULL, out, NULL);
SDL_Texture *tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, out);
SDL_Rect rec = {10, 10, 110, 110};
SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tex, NULL, &rec);
```

Don't worry about my renderer or window etc. I've isolated the problem to somewhere in this code. The image does not appear on the screen, however it does if I create a texture from the loaded surface. Thoughts? I imagine I'm misusing either CreateRGBSurface, or BlitScaled (I did see another question about this, however the solution was unclear).

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Nothing happens. Oops how could I forget that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me I had to do:

```
SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(loaded , SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(out, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
```

For it to work, otherwise some strange blending happens.

The docs page for this function says:

> To copy a surface to another surface (or texture) without blending with the existing data, the blendmode of the SOURCE surface should be
>   set to 'SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE'.

So setting loaded is probably enough.

Edit: In the end I came up with this:

```
struct FreeSurface_Functor
{
    void operator() (SDL_Surface* pSurface) const
    {
        if (pSurface)
        {
            SDL_FreeSurface(pSurface);
        }
    }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, FreeSurface_Functor> SDL_SurfacePtr;

class SDLHelpers
{
public:
    SDLHelpers() = delete;

    static SDL_SurfacePtr ScaledCopy(SDL_Surface* src, SDL_Rect* dstSize)
    {
        SDL_SurfacePtr scaledCopy(SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 
            dstSize->w, dstSize->h, 
            src->format->BitsPerPixel, 
            src->format->Rmask, src->format->Gmask, src->format->Bmask, src->format->Amask));

        // Get the old mode
        SDL_BlendMode oldBlendMode;
        SDL_GetSurfaceBlendMode(src, &oldBlendMode);

        // Set the new mode so copying the source won't change the source
        SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(src, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);

        // Do the copy
        if (SDL_BlitScaled(src, NULL, scaledCopy.get(), dstSize) != 0)
        {
            scaledCopy.reset();
        }

        // Restore the original blending mode
        SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(src, oldBlendMode);
        return scaledCopy;
    }
};
```